# How can I extract the item from futures::stream::wait::Wait in Rust?

Tags: stream, rust

I wrote the following piece of code:

```
let first_row = rows_stream.take(1).wait();
```

And receive the following error (when I actually want to access the element):

```
found struct `futures::stream::wait::Wait`
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It is not clear what you asking

Answer (score 0):

I had to add 2x `unwrap()`:
`let first_row = rows_stream.take(1).wait().unwrap().unwrap()`

Comment: unwrap() is generally a bad idea since it causes panic! in error cases.